# Pandas: Update values of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe with multiple columns (sample shown below). I want to update the values of one particular (population column) column by dividing the values of it by 1000.

```
City     Population
Paris    23456
Lisbon   123466
Madrid   1254
Pekin    86648
```

I have tried 
`df['Population'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x))/1000)`

and

```
df['Population'].apply(lambda x: int(x)/1000)
```

Both give me the error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '...'

Comment: Try this: `pd.to_numeric(df['Population'], errors='coerce').div(1000)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `DataFrame` really does look as presented, then the second example should work just fine (with the `int` not even being necessary):

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
     City  Population
0   Paris       23456
1  Lisbon      123466
2  Madrid        1254
3   Pekin       86648

In [17]: df['Population'].apply(lambda x: x/1000)
Out[17]: 
0     23.456
1    123.466
2      1.254
3     86.648
Name: Population, dtype: float64

In [18]: df['Population']/1000
Out[18]: 
0     23.456
1    123.466
2      1.254
3     86.648
```

However, from the error, it seems like you have the unparsable string `'...'` somewhere in your `Series`, and that the data needs to be cleaned further.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned I do have some unparsable string  '...'


I did add 
    df.fillna(np.NaN)

Looks like that has not helped